# How to set return type hint for function from expression

Tags: python, generics, python-3.9

I am coming from the C++ world and it seems like something trivial, yet I couldn't find anything about it in python.

I want to set the return type from an expression, using a generic type parameter:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

@dataclass
class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    obj: T

    def operation(self) -> __type_of_expr__(self.obj.operation()):
        return self.obj.operation()
```

Yet I haven't seen anything that would take the place of `__type_of_expr__` that would result in a properly working, well hinted code.

In C++, it would be done as the following:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T obj;
    
    auto operation() -> decltype(obj.operation()) {
        return obj.operation();
    }
};
```